# ipad mini wont start after downloading ios 8

Tags: ipad

I was downloading ios 8. it was almost complete and suddenly ipad became dead and couldnt start again? tried rebooting too but couldnt start. Could anyone give an advice please.

Comment: was it plugged in ? did you check for compliance with ios 8?

Comment: How do U reboot it? Try to connect it to computer/laptop with iTunes.